# ¿Agregar un archivo CSS y JS a una vista de Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

He tratado con rutas absolutas y relativas y realmento no he podido agregar estos archivo .css y .js

Codigo de la vista **horario.blade.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="founduss_web/resources/css/estilosHorarios.css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/eventos_horarios_configuracion.js"></script>
```

Arbol de directorios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error del servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los archivos deberían estar en la carpeta `public`, no en resources. Estas trabajando con laravel mix?

Comment: no, estoy usando laravel 6.1.0

Comment: Ok, si pones el archivo en la carpeta `/public/js/` , luego en una vista puedes hacer `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/eventos_horarios_conf.js"></script>`. De todas maneras, sería mejor que laravel mix se ocupe de eso https://laravel.com/docs/master/mix#installation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Los archivo `CSS` y `JS` debes colocarlo en la carpeta public en Laravel y para tener acceso a este debe usar el Helper `asset()`

Este es un ejemplo cuando llamas el `Jquery`, el cual esta en la carpeta vendor dentro de /public:

```
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Para el CSS este es el ejemplo:

```
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Gracias! realmente me ayudo

Answer (score 4):

Ya veo que hay una respuesta aceptada, solo para informar a los que estén acostumbrados a usar npm, Webpack o tecnologías similares, Laravel ofrece un:

#### [Andamiaje JavaScript & CSS](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend#introduction)

Si bien Laravel no dicta qué preprocesadores de JavaScript o CSS utilice, sí proporciona un punto de partida básico usando Bootstrap, React y/o Vue que será útil para muchas aplicaciones.

Por defecto, el archivo Laravel [package.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json) incluye algunos paquetes como lodash y axios para ayudarlo a comenzar a construir su aplicación JavaScript. Siéntase libre de agregar o eliminar del archivo package.json según sea necesario para su propia aplicación. Este archivo es similar a un archivo composer.json, excepto que especifica dependencias de JavaScript en lugar de dependencias de PHP.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
}
```

Una vez que haya configurado las dependencias, puede instalarlas utilizando [Node package manager (NPM)](https://www.npmjs.org/):

```
npm install
```

Una vez que las dependencias se han instalado, puede compilar sus assets usando Laravel Mix. Cuando ejecuta el comando

```
npm run dev
```

Webpack ejecutará las instrucciones en su archivo [webpack.mix.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/webpack.mix.js). Por lo general, su CSS compilado se colocará en el directorio public/css y su JavaScript compilado generalmente se colocará en el directorio public/js.

### [Compila tus assets](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#introduction)

Laravel Mix proporciona una API fluida para definir los pasos de compilación de Webpack para su aplicación Laravel utilizando varios preprocesadores CSS y JavaScript comunes. A través del método simple de encadenamiento, puede definir con fluidez su cartera de assets. Por ejemplo:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

#### [Trabajando con hojas de estilo](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#working-with-stylesheets)

El archivo `webpack.mix.js` es su punto de entrada para toda compilación de assets. Piense en ello como un contenedor de configuración ligero alrededor de Webpack. Las tareas de mezcla se pueden encadenar juntas para definir exactamente cómo se deben compilar sus assets.

[CSS plano](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#plain-css)

Si solo desea concatenar algunas hojas de estilo CSS plano en un solo archivo, puede usar el método de `style`:

```
mix.styles([
    'resources/css/estilosHorarios.css',
    'resources/css/otroEstilo.css'
], 'public/css/all.css');
```

#### [Trabajando con JavaScript](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#working-with-scripts)

Mix proporciona varias funciones para ayudarlo a trabajar con sus archivos JavaScript, como compilar ECMAScript 2015, agrupar módulos, minificar y concatenar archivos JavaScript sin formato. Aún mejor, todo esto funciona a la perfección, sin requerir una onza de configuración personalizada:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

Con esta única línea de código, ahora puede aprovechar:

- Sintaxis ES2015.
- Módulos.
- Compilación de archivos .vue.
- Minificación para entornos de producción.

[Vanilla JS](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#vanilla-js)

Similar a la combinación de hojas de estilo con mix.styles(), también puede combinar y minimizar cualquier número de archivos JavaScript con el método scripts():

```
mix.scripts([
    'public/js/eventos_horarios_configuracion.js',
    'public/js/otroJs.js'
], 'public/js/all.js');
```

Luego en el layout principal de tus vistas los incluyes con:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/all.css') }}">

<script src="{{ mix('/js/all.js') }}"></script>
```