# ¿Como puedo hacer que carguen correctamente las rutas de los archivos css y js en proyecto de Laravel?

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, router

Estoy comenzando en Laravel y resulta que tengo una plantillada tipo Blade de nombre layout.blade.php. En esta plantilla tengo cargado todo el html para heredarlo en las demás paginas. 
Resulta que en esta plantilla tengo todos los css y js que cargan y con la plantilla home.blade.php me carga todo bien pero cuando creo una nueva ruta por ejemplo:

> Route::get('/property/add-property', 'AddPropertyController@index')->name('add-property');

A la hora de ir a la nueva página no me carga ninguno de los archivos css y js porque los está buscando en una ruta que no existe.

Por ejemplo:

> /property/bootstrap.css

¿Como puedo solucionar para que no me agregue /property a las rutas de los css y js?

Rutas de los css

>

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> <!-- Favicon-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugin.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.css"/>
<!-- Custom Css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/color_skins.css">
```

Comment: Por favor añade el código de tu vista, para ver como invocas a dichos archivos

Comment: En blade puedes hacer uso de los helpers asset() o url(), es recomendable, pero si no deseas usarlos, asegurate de invocarlos con las diagonales correctas.

Comment: Esta es la ruta de los css

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Agregar un archivo CSS y JS a una vista de Laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/300135/agregar-un-archivo-css-y-js-a-una-vista-de-laravel)

Comment: Ya lo que hice fue compilar los archivos css y js con laravel.mix y ya funcionó perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo

Utiliza la función asset :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.css')}}"/>
```

**usa esto en todas para los archivos css o js**